# How to return a array of null elements if array doesn't exist in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi Guys I've a Json like this

```
 {
  "_id":"15b9367568b61a0a2891feef",
  "date":1492826657037,
  "sourceId":123",
  "sessionCreationDate":1492826657037,
  "sessionId":"15b9367568dcd6dcd36f7615",
  "actions":[
     {
      "flag":"STARTED_SCROLL"
     },
     {
      "flag":"ARTICLE_MIDDLE"
     }
  ],
  "dateClose":1492826915066
}
```

how ever for some id's the 'actions' array might not exist aswell so something like this is possible

```
{
 "_id":"15b9367568b61a0a2891feef",
 "date":1492826657037,
 "sourceId":123,
 "sessionCreationDate":1492826657037,
 "sessionId":"15b9367568dcd6dcd36f7615"
}
```

my current query using pymongo is

```
db['visits'].aggregate\
        (
                        [
                            {
                            "$match":
                                {
                                  "sourceId":
                                    {
                                        "$exists": True,
                                        "$ne": None
                                    },
                                  "date":
                                    {
                                        "$gt":time.time() * 1000 - (1*60*60*1000)
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        {
                            '$project':
                                {
                                    'sourceId':1,
                            'actions.flag':
                                {
                                    '$ifNull': ['$actions.flag', None]
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    ]
        )
```

which results actions as dictionary `actions': {u'flag': None}` how do I convert this to a list of dictionary like `[actions': {u'flag': [None]}]`? because I want to access the flag variable to insert into my db but calling `['actions'][0]['flag']` in a for loop doesn't work as actions is not a list for those action items returned from mongo query and it breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your $project stage instead:

```
{
    '$project':
        {
            'sourceId': 1,
            'actions.flag':
                {
                    '$ifNull': ['$actions.flag',
                                [None, None]]
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: @Jesse I'm still getting actions as `u'actions': {u'flag': [None, None]}`  what I want is a list like `u'actions': [ {u'flag': [None, None]} ]` those "square braces"

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think what I was looking is wrong I had to replace actions.flag with actions in $project and plugin rest of the thing you've answered and it worked !! thanks